# Question on geometric probability similar to Bertrand's paradox.

Tags: probability

Question: If 2 points are selected at random on the circumference of a circle, find the probability that their distance apart is less than radius of the circle.

The most classical approach is:

> Fix the first point anywhere on the circumference, then there is an arc which subtends 60° on either side of the chosen point, if the second point lies on this arc, then it satisfies the required condition.

My approach:

> Instead of selecting the two points one by one, let's say we are selecting them simultaneously. If at all any two points satisfy the given condition, they must lie on an arc which subtends 60° at centre.

I am getting two different answers, while both the approaches seems valid.
I guess it's similar to the Bertrand's paradox.

Comment: I think you have oriented Q to be clockwise of P, so the two points have not been picked independently. Your diagram conditions the position of Q based on the position of P.

Comment: Even if we consider Q being a point anticlockwise to P on circumference, it still lies in an arc which subtends 60° at centre. Note that I have drawn one more arc, indicating that this arc is not fixed

Comment: My logic is, for any two points selected randomly on the circumference, they must be a part of an arc which subtends 60° at centre, in order to satisfy the given condition

Comment: To answer the probability question though, you have ignored the other possible orientation of P and Q.

Comment: I don't understand how have I ignored the other possible orientations of P and Q, the favourable length where P and Q can lie is that particular arc length which subtends 60° at centre, so to find probability, I divided the favourable length by total length out of where P and Q can be chosen. Note that the 1st approach also uses the same logic, except for the fact that they first fix a point P.

Comment: Bertrand's paradox has to do with different ways you can select two points at random on a circle. There's no error involved in coming up with different answers; the different answers are an inherent ambiguity in the problem statement. Your question seems to be about a simple error in calculation instead (or a difference in the interpretation of the condition, which I consider also to be an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate why your reasoning cannot be correct, first imagine that the question asked instead

> What is the probability that the two points subtend a central angle
> not exceeding $60^\circ$?

You should agree that this alternative phrasing still yields the equivalent result as the original phrasing of the question, irrespective of which method of solution you use, because this is the same criterion used in both the classical solution and your solution.

Now, suppose you generalize the problem:

> What is the probability that the two points subtend a central angle not exceeding $\theta$?

Next, consider the case where $\theta = 180^\circ$:

> What is the probability that the two points subtend a central angle not exceeding $180^\circ$?

Well, the answer to this should be obvious:  the two points cannot ever be separated by more than $180^\circ$ because the farthest apart they can be is if they are on a common diameter.  So the probability should be $1$.

But now look at how the reasoning you used in your solution would yield an answer of $1/2$, not $1$, because you are claiming that the probability is the proportion of the central angle between the two points as a fraction of a full $360^\circ$.

This example should give you some sense of why your reasoning is flawed.  As an exercise, try to articulate a formal argument as to why it doesn't work; i.e., where is the flaw?